# How do I deal with an answer in comments that isn't an answer but not a dupe either?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

How do I deal with an answer in comments that isn't an answer but not a dupe either?

I got this one - [Creating desktops and opening programs on those desktops using applescript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335949/creating-desktops-and-opening-programs-on-those-desktops-using-applescript?noredirect=1#comment433808_335949)
Which I kind of read between the lines on & came up with [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) as a solution.
So I pushed in a comment to "answer to the X of the Y" which fixed it for the OP.

What next?

I can't close as dupe, cos it ain't a dupe.
I can't post as an answer 'cos it's not an answer to the question.

Stuck.

Should it just be left, long-haired, unwashed & unloved, to moulder in the compost of history, or given a short back & sides & recruited to the 'link underground' of efficiency?

Comment: Re: *"Should it just be left, long-haired, unwashed & unloved, to moulder in the compost of history, or given a short back & sides & recruited to the 'link underground' of efficiency?"* - I just love a lot of the descriptions you use! :)

Comment: Does my answer help at all? Let me know here if I'm off the mark as to what you're looking to make as consensus or work through more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone should put up an answer there. It’s great the comments are there for someone to maybe read, but one or two answers would be best here.

There’s always an answer if you can explain the way to do something even if it’s not the something the OP wants or initially thought they needed. Questions are just the excuse to get up answers so always focus on the good and useful answer, the rest can get fixed later with edits or closing as dupe. Be sure to vote up the question - it becomes good based on having a good answer even if objectively it wasn’t good initially and needed edits and comments to become vote worthy and get some answers.

Here's an example - I don't even try to answer the actual question other than to reframe the issue a bit and offer workarounds.

- [Window moved after wake up from sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336030/window-moved-after-wake-up-from-sleep)

Comment: I threw in an answer - I did borrow heavily from my linked one, but made it fresh to fit this question. It did help the OP achieve his goal, though it isn't at all an answer to the question he actually asked ;)